# One-liner to check whether a file exists, then feed it to xargs

Tags: bash, testing, pipe, xargs, one-liner

I have a one-liner that spits out all of the files modified in my current feature branch, which is branched off of a shared, upstream development branch. I then hope to feed the files that exist to the phpcs linter via xargs -- something like this:

```
git diff --name-only shared-upstream-development-branch | grep "\.php$" | xargs test -f {} && echo {} | xargs vendor/bin/phpcs
```

However, when I run this, I get something like the following:

> test: extra argument
> ‘path/to/my/file.php’

I feel like I'm close to having a working solution.

**How can I modify the one-liner above to correctly see if each PHP file still exists, then feed it onward to phpcs?**

I know that everything up through the output of the `grep` command works well, as removing the two parts of the one-liner that refer to xargs gives me a nice list of file names.

(I also tried using `--diff-filter=d` to filter out deleted files, but this does not seem to work with my version of git, as I still get a complaint from phpcs about how a file "does not exist.")

Comment: Short answer - don't. This deserves more than one "line". You have filename strings that may or may not contain path info, spaces or other odd characters in file or directory names, and you have a file system where you want to test their existence, then and action to take if they exist. That's enough complexity of logic to warrant a loop that will want to be careful how it treats the filenames. If you *know* there *cannot* be whitespace or other problematic characters in the file path/names, then it's a bit simpler. Use a loop, and read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs carefully.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. I think you're right, and I found another way to do things. I'm keeping the question open in case someone has a creative way to do this that can be repurposed for different needs in the future.

Answer (score 0):

`&&` separates commands, and is not an argument to `xargs`; you need to execute an explicit shell to use `&&`.

```
xargs sh -c 'test -f "$1" && echo "$1"' _ {}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I try `git diff --name-only origin/deploy/2022-05-12 | grep "\.php$" | xargs sh -c 'test -f "$1" && echo "$1"' _ {} | xargs vendor/bin/phpcs` I get a phpcs error saying `ERROR: You must supply at least one file or directory to process.` So it looks like the echoing is not happening somewhere along the way. I verified this by removing the last part of the command, finding that the remaining part appears to run without any output.